# React JS, Error is not defined no-undef when attempting to obtain first value from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am attempting to output a value from an array, but get the error: array1 is not defined  no-undef

**Code Snippet**:

```
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {  
          array1: [],
        }
      }
```

//**code snippet componentDidMount**:

```
componentDidMount(props) {
    this.setState({array1: [5, 12, 8, 130, 44] })
  }
```

//**code snippet, function**:

```
found = this.state.array1.find((element) => {
    return element > 10;
  });
```

**code snippet:**

```
render(){
console.log(found);
}
```

the page errors out in the arrow function, Could I get some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor should be changed to

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        array1: []
    }
}
```

You haven't defined your `array1` as a state.

Update (Updated answer based on comments)

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        array1: []
    }
    this.found = this.found.bind(this);
}

found() {
    return this.state.array1.find((element) => {
        return element > 10;
    }); 
}

render(){
    console.log(this.found());
}
```

Comment: Vikas - I accidentally deleted the "this.state=" line when I posted my question; In my function, I added "this.state" to "array1', which now  reflects the following:  this.state.array1.find ...but I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'array1' of undefined. Please let me know if you have any additional suggestions ...thank you

Comment: Got it. `array1` is defined as a state, the only problem is that `this` is outside of its context. One way to solve it is

`found = (array1) => {
    return array1.find((element) => {
        return element > 10;
    }); 
}

render(){
    console.log(found(this.state.array1));
}`

P.S - I haven't tested the code

Comment: ...I get the error 'found' is not defined  no-undef . ...on console.log(found(this.state.array1)); ...if I remove found, it return nothing ...please let me know if you have any other suggestion. Thank you

Comment: It should be `console.log(this.found(this.state.array1));`

Answer (score 0):

Without constructor, without binding your function (thanks to class-fields) here is how you render (not console.log) array elements.

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  state = { array: [] };
      
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({array: [5, 12, 8, 130, 44] })
  }
  
  // With some cheating.
  found = () =>
    this.state.array
    .map(el => el < 10 ? undefined : <p>{el}</p> );    
  
  // Maybe nicer one?
  foundAlternative = () => 
    this.state.array
      .filter( el => el > 10 )
      .map( el => <p>{el}</p>);
      
       
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.found()}</div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```