# React JS Why do I get a not defined error for function name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am attempting to output a value stored within an array, but I get the following error:  `"Line 40:  'found'` is not defined  `no-undef`
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error."

The code:

```
 class App extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {  
          array1: [],

        }
      }

      componentDidMount(props) {
        this.setState({ array1: [5, 12, 8, 130, 44] })
      }

      found = (array1) => {
        return array1.find((element) => {
          return element > 10;
        });
      }

      render() {
        console.log(found(this.state.array1));
        return (
          <div className="App">
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

the error occurs on the following line:

```
console.log(found(this.state.array1));
```

...could I get some help with please?

Comment: try `this.found`

Comment: Similar question asked two hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026815/react-js-error-is-not-defined-no-undef-when-attempting-to-obtain-first-value-fr

Answer (score 3):

You have to get `found` from `this` first:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.found(this.state.array1));
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use class function within render , you need to invoke it like `this.found()`

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {  
      array1: [],

    }
  }

  componentDidMount(props) {
    this.setState({ array1: [5, 12, 8, 130, 44] })
  }

  found = (array1) => {
    return array1.find((element) => {
      return element > 10;
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.found(this.state.array1));
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```